# How to choose a vector which is linearly independent from a set of orthogonal vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality, matrix-rank, orthogonal-matrices

I have a non-complete set of orthogonal vectors $V=[\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n]$ with $m > n$ entries.
I would like to choose another vector $\mathbf{w}$ which is linearly independent from $\mathbf{v}_i$ for all $1 \le i \le n$. What is the safest and most stable way to choose such $\mathbf{w}$?
If the entries of $V$ are approximate eigenvectors of an $m \times m$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$, then would  $\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{v}_1+\mathbf{v}_2+\ldots+\mathbf{v}_n)$ be a good choice?

Comment: Given the columns of $V$ are approximate eigenvectors, $\mathbf w$ would approximately be within the span of the columns of $V$. So no, this is not a good choice.

Comment: If you select a column vector $w$ at "random" (say, with i.i.d. normally distributed entries), then $w$ will most likely be linearly independent from the $v_i$ with an astronomically low probability of failure.

Comment: Another option you might find appealing is extending the columns of $V$ into a complete orthogonal basis. This can be done by calculating the nullspace of $V^T$; most software includes a nullspace computation function (such as [null in Matlab](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html) or [Python's null_space](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.null_space.html)).

Comment: You could also take a random vector and make it orthogonal to the columns of $V$ by subtracting an orthogonal projection, i.e. calculating $w - V(V^TV)^{-1}V^Tw$, where we note that $V^TV$ is diagonal, which makes $(V^TV)^{-1}$ a quick calculation. In this case, you could also account for the unlikely possibility that $w$ was inside the column space of $V$ by repeating this process if the result is the zero-vector.